# Limiting processes with Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl, fork

I am trying to use Parallel::ForkManager to control some child processes. I would like to limit the number of processes running concurrently to 10. In total I need to run 20.

I know I could set the process limit at 10 in the first line at the object declaration, but I am also using the $pm object to run child processes that do something different (the current function is much more memory intensive so needs to be limited).

The code I have currently does not work, the run on finish call is never made, so the remaining 10 children never get forked. I don't understand why this is the case- I'd have thought the child would still call the finish code on exit,and decrement the count, but the "if" statement seems to stop this. Could someone explain why this is the case?

Thanks for any help!

```
# Parallel declarations
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);

$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_str_ref) = @_; 
    --$active_jobs;
    })

my $total_jobs = 0;
my $active_jobs = 0;
while( $total_jobs < 20) {
    sleep 300 and next if $active_jobs > 10; 

    my $pid = $pm->start and ++$active_p1_jobs and ++$total_p1_jobs and next;

    my $return = module::function(%args);

    $pm->finish(0, { index => $total_jobs, return => $return }); 
    }

print STDERR "Submitted all jobs, now waiting for children to exit.\n";
$pm->wait_all_children();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to call "type 2" the jobs that are limited to 10.

This is how I'd do it with P::FM:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util            qw( shuffle );
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );
use POSIX                 qw( WNOHANG );
use Time::HiRes           qw( sleep );

use constant MAX_WORKERS       => 30;
use constant MAX_TYPE2_WORKERS => 10;

sub is_type2_job { $_[0]{type} == 2 }

my @jobs = shuffle(
   ( map { { type => 1, data => $_ } } 0..19 ),
   ( map { { type => 2, data => $_ } } 0..19 ),
);

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(MAX_WORKERS);

my $type2_count = 0;
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $job) = @_;
   --$type2_count if is_type2_job($job);
   print "Finished: $pid, $job->{type}, $job->{data}, $job->{result}\n";
});

my @postponed_jobs;
while (@postponed_jobs || @jobs) {
   my $job;
   if (@postponed_jobs && $type2_count < MAX_TYPE2_WORKERS) {
      $job = shift(@postponed_jobs);
   }
   elsif (@jobs) {
      $job = shift(@jobs);
      if ($type2_count >= MAX_TYPE2_WORKERS && is_type2_job($job)) {
         push @postponed_jobs, $job;
         redo;
      }
   }
   # elsif (@postponed_jobs) {
   #     # Already max type 2 jobs being processed,
   #     # but there are idle workers.
   #     $job = shift(@postponed_jobs);
   # }
   else {
      local $SIG{CHLD} = sub { };
      select(undef, undef, undef, 0.300);
      $pm->wait_one_child(WNOHANG);
      redo;
   }

   ++$type2_count if is_type2_job($job);

   my $pid = $pm->start and next;
   $job->{result} = $job->{data} + 100;  # Or whatever.
   $pm->finish(0, $job);
}

$pm->wait_all_children();
```

But this is broken. The code that picks the next job should be done in the middle of `start` (i.e. after it waits for children to finish, but before it forks), not before `start`. This could cause jobs to be run out of order. This isn't the first time I've wished P::FM has a pre-fork callback. Maybe you could ask the maintainer for one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Jobs running out of order is not a concern. However, using `redo` as you describe still doesn't solve my issue. My run_on_finish call is never made, and I don't know why.

Comment: Works for me. Added missing bits to the code in my node. How many lines of output do you get? (`perl script.pl | wc -l`)

Comment: The order of the jobs can affect how long it takes for your program to finish.

Comment: I get 40 lines of output, as expected. However, you don't seem to be incrementing `$type2_count`. If I add `my $pid = $pm->start and ++$type2_count and next;` I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read: `++$type2_count if $job->{type} == 2;` before the fork. I also added a `sleep rand(100);` immediately after the fork to give a chance of getting stuck.

Comment: Fixed. That's exactly what I added.

Comment: I see the problem. If we picked the job when you should (but can't), we wouldn't have a problem because we already waited for a child to end, but right now we're sleeping without waiting for a child to end. We're going to have to copy some code from `wait_all_children`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13964/discussion-between-mubo-and-ikegami)